# Handling AVQueuePlayer when buffer is empty

Tags: ios, audio-streaming, avqueueplayer

I would like to know how to handle playing of audio files from server using AVQueuePlayer when the buffer is empty. I receive buffer is empty via KVO and I am not sure what I suppose to do.
This will happen when device is connected to low bandwidth. Will I able to get audio data in the buffer once the bandwidth is good?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the internet connection isn't interrupted it will keep buffering you have enough data to start playing.

When you get the buffer empty message via KVO you just need to display a message to the user saying that it's buffering, and the player will play when it's full.

Comment: Thanks Winston, but I don't need to start the player once again right?